# Auto setting security settings of a subsite using workflow

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, security

I am wondering if it is possible at all to edit site permission settings using workflow?

I work for a consulting company who takes small projects from various clients and wants to move their document control system onto SharePoint.

I have built a workflow which creates sub-sites using a template, but my boss also wants the sub-sites to have certain security settings such that the company's staff has access to all sub-sites (reading as well as editing), but the clients with only read access to the sub-sites that are dedicated to their project.

Right now all the sub-sites inherit from the main site, which grants everyone at least Read access.  Is it possible to make this adjustment using workflow?

Either within the workflow for creating sub-sites or using a new workflow, as long as it gets the job done.

I am very new to SharePoint, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, out of the box SharePoint 2013 workflows doesn't support permission management. One way you can use 3rd party solutions.

I would recommend you to have a look at [Plumsail Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack). 
It is extended set of workflow actions for SharePoint Designer, it contains [Permission Management](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/permissions-management/) section and workflow [Grant Permission on Site](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/permissions-management/#GrantPermissionOnWeb)

I'm one of the dev team and I know this product very well, that's why I recommend it.

Comment: Hi Roman, I've uploaded the actions pack to our sharepoint site, now when I go to open any workflow in sharepoint designer I get the message 'Server-side activities have been updated. You need to restart Sharepoint Designer to use the updated version of activities'.  I've restarted SPD as well as the computer, but am still getting the exact same message...do you know what may be wrong there?

Comment: Ok so it would seem that I did not clear the local cache...after doing that, the errors are no longer there!

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's very common issue. Feel free to write on the supports' email with any issues.